# jquery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

With `$.post` send data to external php

Have following code (modified variable names) `text_of_the_ad:"<?php echo htmlspecialchars( substr($arr[0]["SomeText"],0,70), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); ?>",`

`text_of_the_ad` in external php will get with `$_POST['text_of_the_ad']`

`$arr[0]["SomeText"]` is text from mysql column `SomeText`

In Chrome Console see `text_of_the_ad:"CITROEN C4 EXCLUSIVE 2.0 HDI DIESEL 5 DOOR HATCH LOW MILEAGE FSH
FULL ",`

[image]

And see error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Why the error? May be because word `FULL` is in the next line and after word `FSH` there is no `",`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support multiline strings just like that. The easiest way to hack around this would probably be to just replace a literal `\n` with `\\n` before echoing:

```
<?php echo str_replace("\n","\\n",htmlspecialchars( substr($arr[0]["SomeText"],0,70), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the line continuation character, which is `\`. So that your source would look like:

```
text_of_the_ad:"CITROEN C4 EXCLUSIVE 2.0 HDI DIESEL 5 DOOR HATCH LOW MILEAGE FSH\
FULL "
```

Multi-line strings in JavaScript must be escaped, but doing it this way is not going to always produce your desired behaviour - i.e. sometimes browsers might insert newline characters, sometimes they might not.